# Separate Strings Between Hypens

Tags: sql, oracle, substr, regexp-substr

I need these characters separated from the following string in oracle sql.

PQ
LAN
RRR

R_RR_RX PQ-LAN-RRR (FYZ)

Comment: How do we know which characters to extract? What rule do you want to apply? Is the rule simply: Show `'PQ LAN RRR'`, if the string contains `'PQ-LAN-RRR'`? Or do you want the characters of certain positions? Or what else?

Comment: And what exactly is it you have problems with? (If it's about certain positions and you tag the request with `substr`, then why don't you use `substr`?)

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to identify what pattern is in the data because you only provided one value for it. I am making a few assumptions in the regular expression, and it will look specifically for dashes as the desired marker, extract what letters or numbers surround the dashes, and ignore everything else. If that is not what you would like, please include more examples of data and expected results, and a short explanation of what the rules are.

Anyhow, this is my attempt:

```
FSITJA@db01 2019-07-18 11:42:38> select regexp_replace('R_RR_RX PQ-LAN-RRR (FYZ)', '^[[:alnum:]_]+ +([[:alnum:]]+)-([[:alnum:]]+)-([[:alnum:]]+).*', '\1 \2 \3')
  2    from dual;

REGEXP_REP
----------
PQ LAN RRR
```